# npm run dev command generate the errors

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, npm-run

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Dhenish\NEXTJS\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Dhenish\NEXTJS\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-07T11_17_19_452Z-debug-0.log

Npm run dev command in terminal.
```

After using this command npx create-next-app@latest

Comment: Have you changed the directory on the terminal to that of the nextjs project?

Comment: C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Dhenish\NEXTJS
Currently I am in this directory and inside this my project dir. So do you mean I need to change it with cd <project name> ??

Comment: Yes. Try that and run the command in that directory